# Problem with Right Angle Triangle

Tags: tikz-pgf

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{output-decimal-marker={,}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]%,cap=round,>=latex]

\coordinate [label=left:$C$] (A) at (-1.5cm,-1.cm);
\coordinate [label=right:$A$] (C) at (1.5cm,-1.0cm);
\coordinate [label=above:$B$] (B) at (1.5cm,1.0cm);
\draw (A) -- node[sloped,above] {$\textrm{Hypotenous}$} (B) -- node[right,rotate=-90,xshift=-9mm] {$\textrm{Oposite Side}$} (C) -- node[below] {$\textrm{Adjacent Side}$} (A);

\draw (1.25cm,-1.0cm) rectangle (1.5cm,-0.75cm);
\tkzMarkAngle[size=0.5cm,color=black,mark=](C,A,B) 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Question:1 In the given figure you will see that the word opposite side is mixing with the side AB. I want to modify this.

Question:2 Second thing is i would like to label angle ACB as thita(its a Greek later \theta).

Comment: Quick question: why have you labeled coordinate `(A)` as `C` and coordinate `(C)` as `A`? It makes your code look messy, to be honest. Also, you can remove all the `\textrm{ }` constructs, as the label is text by default.

Answer (score 4):

For your first question, you only need to specify that you want the label to be above the line, i.e. type:

```
node[above right,rotate=-90,xshift=-9mm] {$\textrm{Oposite Side}$}
```

This will place the label as desired.

NB: you may type `below` to have this label on the other side.

Comment: I don't think it needs to be `above right`, just `above` would work (maybe).

Comment: I have just tested it, and this code without `right` will put the label on the top right side instead of middle of the side.

Comment: Use `node[above,sloped]` instead, that is the easiest and most used solution.

Answer (score 2):

Addition of `\tkzLabelAngle` can be used to label theta. Modified code below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{output-decimal-marker={,}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]%,cap=round,>=latex]

\coordinate [label=left:$C$] (A) at (-1.5cm,-1.cm);
\coordinate [label=right:$A$] (C) at (1.5cm,-1.0cm);
\coordinate [label=above:$B$] (B) at (1.5cm,1.0cm);
\draw (A) -- node[sloped,above] {$\textrm{Hypotenous}$} (B) -- node[above right,rotate=-90,xshift=-9mm] {$\textrm{Oposite Side}$} (C) -- node[below] {$\textrm{Adjacent Side}$} (A);

\draw (1.25cm,-1.0cm) rectangle (1.5cm,-0.75cm);
\tkzMarkAngle[size=0.5cm,color=black,mark=](C,A,B) 
\tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.65](C,A,B){$\theta$}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You make it so easy.

Answer (score 2):

The same code but change your code in 18th line as shown below

```
\draw (A) -- node[sloped,above] {$\textrm{Hypotenous}$} (B) -- node[left,rotate=90,xshift= 11mm, yshift=-3mm] {$\textrm{Oposite Side}$} (C) -- node[below] {$\textrm{Adjacent Side}$} (A);
```

[image: triangle]